# How to copy a PlaceholderField in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

We are using Django CMS on our site with the PlaceholderField on a custom model.

I'm looking to add Draft / Timed Edits to a custom model that uses the PlaceholderField.

But as part of that I need to be able to copy the PlaceholderField.

I saw this is possible in the web interface, and tried to use the PlaceholderAdminMixin class and it's copy_plugins method, but it looks to be too tied to the web site (ran into issues faking the 'admin_site' variable :)  I need to do this outside of the web interface/just in code.

Anyone have any suggestions/thoughts on how to best do this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy plugins from a `PlaceholderField` to another placeholder you can do:

```
from cms.utils.copy_plugins import copy_plugins_to


class YouModel(models.Model):
    content = PlaceholderField('content')


instance = YourModel.objects.get(pk=1)

# language can be none if you want to copy all plugins regardless
# of language
plugins = instance.content.get_plugins_list(language=language)

# target_placeholder is a placeholder instance
copy_plugins_to(plugins, target_placeholder, no_signals=True)
```

Keep in mind though that `copy_plugins_to` is an internal so it can change :)